# Problem about Growing a Linearly Independent Set

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces

I am working on the following problem:

> Let $B_1=\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_k\}$ and $B_2=\{w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_{k+1}\}$ be two linearly independent sets of vectors from the same vector space $U$. Prove that there exists an index $i\in[k+1]$ so that the set $B_1\cup w_i$ of vectors is linearly independent.

I have tried two approaches and have gotten stuck with both.

Approach 1:

> Since $B_2$ is a linearly independent set of vectors from the vector space $U$ with $|B_2|={k+1}$, it follows that if $B$ is a basis of $U$ then $|B|\geq k+1$. This means that $\text{dim}(U)\geq k+1$. Now suppose for contradiction that for all $i\in[k+1]$, $B_1\cup w_i$ is a linearly dependent set of vectors.

I was trying to conclude here that since $B_1\cup w_i$ is a linearly dependent set of vectors for all $i\in[k+1]$, it follows that any basis $B$ of $U$ will have $|B|\leq k$. But I think that only work if $B_1\cup w_i$ is a linearly dependent set of vectors for all $w_i\in U$.

Approach 2:

> Since $B_1$ is a linearly independent set of vectors, it follows that if
> $$a_1\cdot v_1+a_2\cdot v_2+\ldots+a_k\cdot v_k=0$$
> for some scalars $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k$ then $a_1=a_2=\ldots=a_k=0$.
> Similarly, since $B_2$ is a linearly independent set of vectors, it follows that if
> $$b_1\cdot w_1+b_2\cdot w_2+\ldots+b_{k+1}\cdot w_{k+1}=0$$
> for some scalars $b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_{k+1}$ then $b_1=b_2=\ldots=b_{k+1}=0$.
> Now suppose for contradiction that for all $i\in[k+1]$, $B_1\cup w_i$ is linearly dependent.
> This means that there exists scalars $c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_{k+1}$ not all zero such that
> $$c_1\cdot v_1+c_2\cdot v_2+\ldots+c_k\cdot v_k +c_{k+1}\cdot w_i=0$$
> Since the $c_i's$ are not all $0$ and $B_1$ is algebraically independent, $c_{k+1}\neq 0$.Then
> $$w_i=-\frac{c_1}{c_{k+1}}\cdot v_1-\ldots-\frac{c_k}{c_{k+1}}\cdot v_k$$
> which means that $w_i\in\text{span}(B_1)$ for all $i\in[k+1]$. In other words, $B_2\subseteq\text{span}(B_1)$.

And now I am stuck on deriving a contradiction.

Can I get some guidance? I think I am overlooking something here.

Comment: Assume all the $w_i$ are in the span of $B_1$ then prove this implies they're linearly dependent.

Comment: Take approach2. Replace the (wrong) statement "Without loss of generality, assume $c_1≠0$" with "since the $c_i$'s are not all $0$ and $B_1$ is algebraically independent, $c_{k+1}\ne0$". Derive $B_2\subset span(B_1).$

Comment: @AnneBauval Okay I think I get what you guys are saying. Can you explain a bit more on how we know $c_{k+1}\neq 0$? I still don't fully follow that part. Also, I have updated my approach 2 and have derived that $B_2\subseteq\text{span}(B_1)$, but I don't know how to proceed next.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote (and you copied) "*algebraically* independent" when I meant *linearly*. If $c_{k+1}$ was $0$ the remaining $\sum_{i=1}^kc_iv_i=0$ (with $c_1,...,c_k$ not all $0$) would imply $B_1$ dependent.

Comment: "Next", do you know a theorem about the maximal size of a linearly independent subset in a space of given (finite) dimension?

Comment: @AnneBauval if you remind me of the statement of the theorem I will probably remember.  However looking at the problem again with a fresh mind, if $B_2\subseteq \text{span}(B_1)$ then doesn't that mean $\text{span}(B_2)\subseteq\text{span}(B_1)$ and this is a contradiction as $B_2$ is strictly larger linearly independent set so how can it's span be contained inside of $B_1's$? Does that make sense? Is that hand wavy? Is the theorem you are referring to mention something similar to this?

Comment: Yes it is. I.e. something has to be proved but is probably already in your toolbox and can be used as such: either "my theorem" (in a space $V$ of dimension $k$ -like $V:=span(B_1)$- a set of $>k$ vectors -like $B_2$- is always linearly dependent, or equivalently the maximal size of an independent set is $k$), or "your (implicit) theorem", ofc equivalent (the dimension of every subspace of $V$ -like $span(B_2)$ once proved that $B_2\subset span(B_1)$- is $\le\dim(V)$).

Comment: @AnneBauval great, thank you for your help! One last thing I wanted to ask, do you mean $\subseteq$ or $\subset$? Does it matter in this case?

Comment: I mean $\subseteq$ which, following many authors, I write $\subset$ (writing $\subsetneq$ for your $\subset$). In our case ($B_2\subset span(B_1)$) it is equivalent, since $B_2$ is finite and $span(B_1)$ is infinite.

Answer (score 1):

We can reduce the statement to one about the dimension of $\mathbf{k}^{k}$, where $\mathbf{k}$ denotes the ground field.

I argue the contrapositive. Assume that each $B_{1} \cup w_{i}$ is linearly dependent, i.e., there exist scalars $c_{i,0},c_{i,1},\dots,c_{i,k} \in \mathbf{k}$ such that at least one is nonzero and
$$ c_{i,0}w_{i} + \sum_{j = 1}^{k} c_{i,j} v_{j} = 0. $$
In fact, we know $c_{i,0}$ must be nonzero, for otherwise, we would have a nontrivial linear combination in $B_{1}$. Assume without loss of generality that $c_{i,0} = 1$.
$$ w_{i} = \sum_{j = 1}^{k} (-c_{i,j}) v_{j}. $$
In other words, for each $1 \leq i \leq k+1$, we have a vector $c_{i}$ in $\mathbf{k}^{k}$ such that
$$ w_{i} = -\begin{pmatrix} & & \\ v_{1} & \cdots & v_{k} \\ & & \end{pmatrix} c_{i}, $$
where the $j$th row of $c_{i}$ is defined to be $c_{i,j}$. Because $\mathbf{k}^{k}$ has dimension $k$, the $c_{i}$ are linearly dependent. Once more, this means there exist $\lambda_{1},\dots,\lambda_{k+1}$, not all zero, such that
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} \lambda_{i}c_{i} = 0. $$
Multiply from the left by
$$ -\begin{pmatrix} & & \\ v_{1} & \cdots & v_{k} \\ & & \end{pmatrix} $$
to get
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} \lambda_{i}w_{i} = 0. $$

In conclusion, if the $w_{i}$ were on the other hand *linearly independent*, then it cannot be the case each $B_{1} \cup w_{i}$ is also linearly independent.

Let us examine a concrete example. Consider if $\mathbf{k} = \mathbf{R}$, $k = 2$, and
$$ v_{1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad v_{2} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
$$ w_{1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}, \quad w_{2} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}, \quad w_{3} = \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix}. $$
The first step in the proof is to express each $w_{i}$ as a linear combination in the $v_{i}$. Specifically, the vectors $c_{i}$ in the proof come out to be
$$ c_{1} = \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ -4 \end{pmatrix}, \quad c_{2} = \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ -5 \end{pmatrix}, \quad c_{3} = \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ -6 \end{pmatrix}. $$
Row reduction on the matrix
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 3 & 3 \\ -4 & -5 & -6 \end{pmatrix} $$
yields
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} $$
from which we read off a nonzero vector in the kernel, namely
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}. $$
In other words, we can take $\lambda_{1} = 1, \lambda_{2} = -2, \lambda_{3} = 1$. Indeed,
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix} - 2 \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix} = 0. $$